# Android Studio Response data Error using Retrofit and LazyColumn composable

Tags: android, kotlin, http, retrofit, lazycolumn

If I use a custom calendar to select a day of the week, I want to communicate with the server and receive a response from the data stored on that day of the week to associate it with the LazyColumn Composables.

I've created the TodoItem and TodoItemList functions, but I'm asking because I don't know how to connect the values by communicating with the server and receiving the data response.

**And now I have the following error.**

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: D:\lotus_aos\app\src\main\java\com\example\todo_android\Screen\CalendarScreen.kt: (321, 80): Classifier 'ReadTodoResponse' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
```

In fact, when I clicked on a day of the week using a custom calendar, I communicated with the server to get the response value and put it in Log if the data for that day of the week was saved.

But now, when I click on a day of the week in a custom calendar, I ask because I'm not sure how to get the data stored on the server and connect it to LazyColumn to put it in.

The relevant codes are as follows.

**ReadTodoRequest.kt**

```
package com.example.todo_android.Request.TodoRequest

import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.ReadTodoResponse
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Header
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface ReadTodoRequest {
    @GET("/todo/todo/")
    fun requestReadTodo(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Query("year") year: Int,
        @Query("month") month: Int,
        @Query("day") day: Int
        ): Call<ReadTodoResponse>
}
```

**ReadTodoResponse.kt**

```
package com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class ReadTodoResponse(
    @SerializedName("resultCode")
    val resultCode: Int,
    @SerializedName("data")
    val data: ArrayList<RToDoResponse>
)


// 응답값으로 data의 디테일한 값들
data class RToDoResponse(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val year: Int,
    val month: Int,
    val day: Int,
    val done: Boolean,
    val writer: String
)
```

**TodoItem.kt**

```
package com.example.todo_android.Component

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.itemsIndexed
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.todo_android.Data.Todo.ReadTodo
import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.ReadTodoResponse
import java.time.Month
import java.time.MonthDay
import java.time.Year

//@Composable
//fun TodoList(token : String, year : Int, month : Int, day : Int) {
//    TodoItem(number = 10)
//}
//
//@Composable
//fun TodoItem(number: Int) {
//    Card(
//        modifier = Modifier
//            .padding(12.dp)
//            .border(width = 2.dp, color = Color.LightGray)
//            .fillMaxWidth()
//            .height(80.dp)
//            .background(color = Color.White),
//
//        ) {
//        Column(
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .fillMaxWidth()
//                .background(color = Color.White),
//            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
//            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
//        ) {
//            Text(
//                text = "체크리스트 입니다 ${number}"
//            )
//        }
//    }
//}

@Composable
fun TodoItem(todo: ReadTodoResponse) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(45.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
    ) {
        Surface() {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = todo.data.toString(),
                    Modifier.padding(10.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TodoItemList(todoList: List<ReadTodoResponse>) {
    LazyColumn{
        itemsIndexed(items = todoList) { index, item ->
            TodoItem(todo = item)
        }
    }
}
```

**CalendarScreen.kt**

```
package com.example.todo_android.Screen

import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.animation.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.todo_android.Component.TodoItemList
import com.example.todo_android.Data.Todo.CreateTodo
import com.example.todo_android.Data.Todo.UpdateTodo
import com.example.todo_android.Navigation.Action.RouteAction
import com.example.todo_android.Request.TodoRequest.CreateTodoRequest
import com.example.todo_android.Request.TodoRequest.DeleteTodoRequest
import com.example.todo_android.Request.TodoRequest.ReadTodoRequest
import com.example.todo_android.Request.TodoRequest.UpdateTodoRequest
import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.CreateTodoResponse
import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.DeleteTodoResponse
import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.UpdateTodoResponse
import com.example.todo_android.Util.MyApplication
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.Kalendar
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.color.KalendarThemeColor
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.component.day.config.KalendarDayColors
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.model.KalendarDay
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.model.KalendarEvent
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.model.KalendarType
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.ReadTodoResponse as Read

fun createTodo(token: String, year: String, month: String, day: String, title: String) {

    var createTodoResponse: CreateTodoResponse? = null

    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://plotustodo-ctzhc.run.goorm.io/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    var createTodoRequest: CreateTodoRequest = retrofit.create(CreateTodoRequest::class.java)

    createTodoRequest.requestCreateTodo(token, CreateTodo(year, month, day, title))
        .enqueue(object : Callback<CreateTodoResponse> {

            // 실패 했을때
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<CreateTodoResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("error", t.message.toString())
            }

            // 성공 했을때
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<CreateTodoResponse>,
                response: Response<CreateTodoResponse>,
            ) {
                createTodoResponse = response.body()

                Log.d("createTodo", "token : " + MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", ""))
                Log.d("createTodo", "resultCode : " + createTodoResponse?.resultCode)
                Log.d("createTodo", "data : " + createTodoResponse?.data)

            }
        })
}

fun readTodo(token: String, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {

    var readTodoResponse: Read? = null

    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://plotustodo-ctzhc.run.goorm.io/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    var readTodoRequest: ReadTodoRequest = retrofit.create(ReadTodoRequest::class.java)

    readTodoRequest.requestReadTodo(token, year, month, day)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<Read> {

            //실패할 경우
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Read>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("readTodo", t.message.toString())
            }

            //성공할 경우
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<Read>,
                response: Response<Read>,
            ) {
                readTodoResponse = response.body()

                Log.d("readTodo", "token : " + MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", ""))
                Log.d("readTodo", "resultCode : " + readTodoResponse?.resultCode)
                Log.d("readTodo", "data : " + readTodoResponse?.data)
            }
        })
}

fun updateTodo(
    token: String,
    year: String,
    month: String,
    day: String,
    title: String,
    done: String,
) {

    var updateTodoResponse: UpdateTodoResponse? = null

    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://plotustodo-ctzhc.run.goorm.io/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    var updateTodoRequest: UpdateTodoRequest = retrofit.create(UpdateTodoRequest::class.java)

    updateTodoRequest.requestUpdateTodo(token, UpdateTodo(year, month, day, title, done))
        .enqueue(object : Callback<UpdateTodoResponse> {

            // 실패 했을때
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<UpdateTodoResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("updateTodo", t.message.toString())
            }

            // 성공 했을때
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<UpdateTodoResponse>,
                response: Response<UpdateTodoResponse>,
            ) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    updateTodoResponse = response.body()

                    Log.d("updateTodo", "token : " + MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", ""))
                    Log.d("updateTodo", "resultCode : " + updateTodoResponse?.resultCode)
                    Log.d("updateTodo", "data : " + updateTodoResponse?.data)
                } else {
                    Log.e("updateTodo", "resultCode : " + response.body())
                    Log.e("updateTodo", "code : " + response.code())
                }
            }
        })
}

fun deleteTodo(
    token: String,
) {
    var deleteTodoResponse: DeleteTodoResponse? = null

    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://plotustodo-ctzhc.run.goorm.io/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    var deleteTodoRequest: DeleteTodoRequest = retrofit.create(DeleteTodoRequest::class.java)

    deleteTodoRequest.requestDeleteTodo(token)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<DeleteTodoResponse> {

            // 실패 했을때
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DeleteTodoResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("updateTodo", t.message.toString())
            }

            // 성공 했을때
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<DeleteTodoResponse>,
                response: Response<DeleteTodoResponse>,
            ) {
                deleteTodoResponse = response.body()

                Log.d("deleteTodo", "token : " + MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", ""))
                Log.d("deleteTodo", "resultCode : " + deleteTodoResponse?.resultCode)
                Log.d("deleteTodo", "data : " + deleteTodoResponse?.data)
            }
        })
}


@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun CalendarScreen(routeAction: RouteAction) {

    val states = listOf(
        "월간",
        "주간"
    )
    var selectedOption by remember { mutableStateOf(states[1]) }

    val onSelectionChange = { text: String -> selectedOption = text }

    var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    val token = "Token ${MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", "")}"

//    val year = "2023"
//    val month = "2"
//    val day = "6"
//    val token = "Token ${MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", "")}"
//    val title = "qkrwhdwns"
//    val done = "true"

    var year by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var month by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var day by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    val title = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val done = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(15.dp))

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp))
                .background(Color(0xffe9e9ed))
                .padding(4.dp)
        )
        {
            states.forEach { text ->
                Text(
                    text = text,
                    color =
                    if (text == selectedOption) {
                        Color.Black
                    } else {
                        Color.Gray
                    },
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp))
                        .clickable {
                            onSelectionChange(text)
                            isVisible = !isVisible
                        }
                        .background(
                            if (text == selectedOption) {
                                Color.White
                            } else {
                                Color(0xffe9e9ed)
                            }
                        )
                        .padding(
                            vertical = 5.dp,
                            horizontal = 16.dp,
                        )
                )
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(29.dp))

        AnimatedVisibility(isVisible)
        {
            Kalendar(
                kalendarType = KalendarType.Oceanic(),
                kalendarDayColors = KalendarDayColors(Color.Black, Color.Black),
                kalendarThemeColor = KalendarThemeColor(
                    backgroundColor = Color.White,
                    dayBackgroundColor = Color(0xffFBE3C7),
                    headerTextColor = Color.Black),
                onCurrentDayClick = { kalendarDay: KalendarDay, kalendarEvents: List<KalendarEvent> ->

                    year = kalendarDay.localDate.year
                    month = kalendarDay.localDate.monthNumber
                    day = kalendarDay.localDate.dayOfMonth

                    Log.d("Kalendar",
                        "year: ${kalendarDay.localDate.year}, month : ${kalendarDay.localDate.month}, day: ${kalendarDay.localDate.dayOfMonth}")


                    readTodo(token, year, month, day)

                    
                })
        }

        AnimatedVisibility(!isVisible) {
            Kalendar(
                kalendarType = KalendarType.Firey,
                kalendarDayColors = KalendarDayColors(Color.Black, Color.Black),
                kalendarThemeColor = KalendarThemeColor(
                    backgroundColor = Color.White,
                    dayBackgroundColor = Color(0xffFBE3C7),
                    headerTextColor = Color.Black),
                onCurrentDayClick = { kalendarDay: KalendarDay, kalendarEvents: List<KalendarEvent> ->

                    year = kalendarDay.localDate.year
                    month = kalendarDay.localDate.monthNumber
                    day = kalendarDay.localDate.dayOfMonth

                    Log.d("Kalendar",
                        "year: ${kalendarDay.localDate.year}, month : ${kalendarDay.localDate.month}, day: ${kalendarDay.localDate.dayOfMonth}")


                    readTodo(token, year, month, day)
                })
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(29.dp))

        Text(text = day.toString())

        TodoItemList(todoList = com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.ReadTodoResponse)


//        Scaffold(floatingActionButton = {
//            FloatingActionButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
//                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "todolist 추가")
//            }
//        }) {
//            LazyColumn {
//                TodoItem()
//            }
//        }

//        Surface(
//            shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .wrapContentSize()
//        ) {}


//        Button(
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .width(300.dp)
//                .height(50.dp),
//            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFBE3C7)),
//            onClick = { readTodo(token, year, month, day) }
//        ) {
//            Text(text = "TODO 조회", color = Color.Black)
//        }
//
//        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
//
//        Button(
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .width(300.dp)
//                .height(50.dp),
//            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFBE3C7)),
//            onClick = { createTodo(token, year, month, day, title) }
//        ) {
//            Text(text = "TODO 작성", color = Color.Black)
//        }
//
//        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
//
//        Button(
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .width(300.dp)
//                .height(50.dp),
//            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFBE3C7)),
//            onClick = { updateTodo(token, year, month, day, title, done) }
//        ) {
//            Text(text = "TODO 수정", color = Color.Black)
//        }
//
//        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
//
//        Button(
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .width(300.dp)
//                .height(50.dp),
//            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFBE3C7)),
//            onClick = { deleteTodo(token) }
//        ) {
//            Text(text = "TODO 삭제", color = Color.Black)
//        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your question specifically about what's causing the compilation error you mentioned? Can you please highlight the line of code where the error occurs?

Comment: @Egor on CalendarScreen, there is error on this code.

 TodoItemList(todoList = com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.ReadTodoResponse)

Comment: Where is `ReadTodoResponse` declared? I don't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: @Egor sorry, i didnt post it. i edited it! check plz

Comment: Well, `ReadTodoResponse` is not an object, hence you can't reference it statically like you do in `TodoItemList(todoList = com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.ReadTodoResponse)`. What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: @Egor because i wanna try to link to LazyColumn and retrofit response data

Comment: @Egor can u explain me how to code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with the line `TodoItemList(todoList = com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.ReadTodoResponse)`. This is the same as just writing `TodoItemList(todoList = ReadTodoResponse)`. Note that there are no `()` after `ReadTodoResponse`, so in the Kotlin world this is handled like passing an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html). `ReadTodoResponse` is a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html), so you need to instantiate it: `ReadTodoResonse(...)`.

I can see that you instantiate one when you handle the response body here: `readTodoResponse = response.body()`, but then it looks like you never use it. I suggest you use a [StateFlow](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow) to pass your response to some state holder class, such as a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). Your compose views then can access the state from the ViewModel. Later on, this kind of architecture will make it easier to implement unit tests and to refactor your code. You can read more about app architecture [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/intro).

Comment: can u explain me how to code it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).